# JSON response object using stream

Tags: spring, spring-boot, stream

I'm using Spring Boot. I'm generating a JSON response from a DAO.
My final JSON response has these three properties:

```
                {
                    "A": "00011",
                    "B": "abc",
                    "C": "RDG"
                }
```

The output should look like this:

```
               {
                    "A": "00011",
                    "B": "abc"
                }
```

In the below code TModel has inherited properties from the DAO with all three fields A, B, C. This is being returned back to my controller. How do I get rid of field `C` in my JSON response?

Code:

```
public TModel(List<TModel> tEntities) {
        List<TModel> responseEntities= tEntities.stream()
                .filter(model -> model.getStatus().equals("RDG"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: If you allowed changing the response model just put the @JsonIgnore annotation above the C field

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1)**
Add @JsonIgnore annotation over the field c

**Solution 2)**
Create a DTO object, without the field C. You can use tools like MapStruct, that help to map between the domain and DTO objects.

I prefer solution 2, as this is cleaner.